# Sound is outputting through both the built-in speakers and external speakers

Tags: 14.04, sound, xubuntu, mac

I'm using Xubuntu on a iMac.  When I have a output device attached (whether that be headphones or speakers) it plays through both the built-in audio, along with the device and I'd like to prevent this from happening.  I'm not very experienced with Linux, Ubuntu, or Xubuntu, so any feedback or additional information I can get would be helpful.

`Edit (Information)`

- When running the command `pavucontrol`, and going to the "Output Devices" tab.  The only connected device shown is "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" (even when selecting "All devices")

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been searching for a solution to this for over year and haven't found one yet. First, check if auto muting is enabled in `alsamixer`. If auto muting is enabled, then what I do is to mute a channel in ALSA mixer. The channel you have to mute you'll need to find by trial and error. Open a terminal and start the `alsamixer` program. Change cards if you think the channels are too few. The last few columns will contain one for the auto muting option, which can have various values. Toggle to see if any one is the effect you want. If none suit you, experiment with disabling channels until it's satisfactory. (Press <kbd>0</kbd> when a channel is highlighted to set volume to zero, or press <kbd>m</kbd> to mute).

Comment: Thank you, this really helped out.  All the other related answers I saw did not have an answer like this.

Comment: Wait...  The problem hasn't been fixed.  I've tried adjusting some things around...  and there doesn't seem to be a way to turn my built in speakers off.

Comment: When I turn the option "Speaker" all the way down to 0, but "headphones" all the way up it still plays out the built-in speakers.  The only other way I've found to turn off the built-in is by turning "PCM" all the way down or "Master Volume", but these also turn down everything else.

Comment: Nevermind, I've seemed to fix the issue.  When I turned "Speaker" all the way down I think it was still playing because "Bass Speaker" was still on.  But never the matter, I've fixed it with your help.

Comment: I've found another issue.  When I use the volume buttons it basically resets back to it's original state.  The speakers go all the way back up, and headphones all the way down.  Is it possible to change when I use the volume buttons it adjusts the headphones instead of the speakers.  (Remember I'm planning on never using the built in speakers)

Comment: @Xero Sorry, that is also something that I haven't managed to do yet. The only luck I had was when I was using the Enlightenment DE, which had a plugin for volume control which only changed the ALSA levels.

Answer (score 0):

setting auto-mute = 0 works for Toshiba Satellite A105 ( enables sound on the laptop speakers finally )

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: norm a little more information please.